# MDX Question - Using Top Count with Rank/Order Function

Tags: mdx, mdx-query

How do I use a top count so it only returns the first 2 records with the highest sales for each sales territory group (North America, Pacific, etc...)

```
WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Group_Ranking_InternetSales] AS
   RANK( [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].CurrentMember,
   ORDER( [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].[Sales Territory Group].Members , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], BDESC)
   ) 

   MEMBER [Measures].[Group_Territory_Ranking_InternetSales] AS
   RANK(( [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].CurrentMember,   [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].CurrentMember),
   ORDER( CROSSJOIN([Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].CurrentMember,  [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]) , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], BDESC)
   ) 
SELECT 
      {
   [Measures].[Group_Ranking_InternetSales]
   ,[Measures].[Group_Territory_Ranking_InternetSales] 
   , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      } ON COLUMNS,
   (
           ORDER  ([Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].[Sales Territory Group], [Measures].[Group_Ranking_InternetSales] , BASC ) 
   ,ORDER  ([Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country], [Measures].[Group_Territory_Ranking_InternetSales] , BASC ) 
   )
   ON ROWS 
FROM
      [Adventure Works]
```

The end result should be that it removes the highlighted row below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try now

```
                WITH 
            MEMBER [Measures].[Group_Ranking_InternetSales] AS
            RANK( [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].CurrentMember,
            ORDER( [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].[Sales Territory Group].Members , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], BDESC)
            ) 

            MEMBER [Measures].[Group_Territory_Ranking_InternetSales] AS
            RANK(( [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].CurrentMember,   [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].CurrentMember),
            ORDER( CROSSJOIN([Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].CurrentMember,  [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country]) , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], BDESC)
            ) 
            SELECT 
            {
            [Measures].[Group_Ranking_InternetSales]
            ,[Measures].[Group_Territory_Ranking_InternetSales] 
            , [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
            } ON COLUMNS,
            filter(///Added this
            (
            ORDER  ([Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Group].[Sales Territory Group], [Measures].[Group_Ranking_InternetSales] , BASC ) 
            ,ORDER  ([Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].[Sales Territory Country], [Measures].[Group_Territory_Ranking_InternetSales] , BASC ) 
            )
            ,[Measures].[Group_Territory_Ranking_InternetSales]<3) ///Added this
            ON ROWS 
            FROM
            [Adventure Works]
```